# nuxt3 A composable that requires access to the Nuxt instance was called outside of a plugin, Nuxt hook, Nuxt middleware, or Vue setup function

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am starting in nuxt 3, I am working on a project in which we have centralized what is the useFetch in a composable in which we have decided to place

```
const config = useRuntimeConfig();
```

to use environment variables but we get the following error

> [nuxt] A composable that requires access to the Nuxt instance was called outside of a plugin, Nuxt hook, Nuxt middleware, or Vue setup function

when the composable is called from a store of pinia

here is the code of the composable

```
import { UseFetchOptions } from "nuxt/app";
const config = useRuntimeConfig();
export function useApiFetch<T>(path: string, options: UseFetchOptions<T> = {}) {
 return useFetch(config.public.BASE_API_URL + path,{
    ...options,
  });
}
```

here where we use it for example

```
export const useAuthStore = defineStore("auth", () => {
  const user = ref<User | null>(null);
  const isLoggedIn = computed(() => !!user.value);
  async function logout() {
    await useApiFetch("/logout", { method: "POST" });
    user.value = null;
    token.value = null;
    navigateTo("/auth");
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

`useFetch` is a composable and isn't a direct replacement for `fetch` function. Composables are supposed to be used in the body of component setup, any other usage needs to be conformed.

`useRuntimeConfig` should be called in the body of a composable where it's used:

```
export function useApiFetch<T>(...) {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig();
   return useFetch(config.public.BASE_API_URL + path,
   ..
```

`useFetch` should be called once on store creation and the object needs to be reused across the store:

```
defineStore("auth", () => {
  const logoutFetch = useApiFetch("/logout", { method: "POST", immediate: false });
  ...
  async function logout() {
    await logoutFetch.execute();
    ...
```

This puts the restriction on the use of `auth` store, it's limited to the places that are allowed for [Nuxt composables](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch#usefetch):

> useFetch is a composable meant to be called directly in a setup function, plugin, or route middleware.

Comment: but the error is not in the composable of useFetch it is the composable I have made, useApiFetch which is my composable where I want to make use of environment variables defined in the .env file.

Comment: There's nothing in your composable itself that makes it a composable, it's just a function with "use" prefix. Its the use of builtin composables that makes a difference and puts the restrictions

Comment: ok, it is not a composable, but inside it I want to use the runtimeconfig configurations and then make the requests without getting the error mentioned above, I do not know if I am wrong or I have not understood very well.

Comment: I see, but runtimeconfig doesn't seem to be relevant to the problem. The problem is that you called useFetch asynchronously at random time, while you can't. useApiFetch (more specifically, useFetch) needs to be synchronously called in the body of pinia store setup function, and pinia store needs to be accessed in specific places listed in the post. This fulfills the requirements for the use of builtin composables, which useFetch is. This requires the changes in code that are shown in the answer.

Comment: I understand your answer my friend, but I indicated the runtimeconfig because I have removed it from the code that I have shared, I have left it with fixed values of the code and I have not had the error, that's why I mentioned the runtimeconfig.

Comment: I see. It's not shown where useRuntimeConfig is called. If it's called at the wrong time this would explain the error too and needs to be addressed the same way; all use... functions shouldn't be called anywhere but the described places. If it's called in the body of useApiFetch in order to use `config`, it should be fine at this point

Comment: Sorry, you are right I have not placed where I call runtimeconfig, I have updated the code section where I call const config = useRuntimeConfig();, and that is where I get the error.

Comment: I updated the post for completeness. Should work ok as long as general rules for the use of composables are followed